# VS Code SSH Remote wont connect to my school network anymore

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code

I've been using the ssh extension for a long time now and it just stopped working, it does connect randomly in one out of 10 tries.
I've tried the older version of the extension, setting the use localserver to false
Please help me, I need it for my school work
Although I can perfectly login prom putty or anywhere else

Here is the output

```
    [17:47:56.521] Log Level: 2
[17:47:56.525] remote-ssh@0.51.0
[17:47:56.525] win32 x64
[17:47:56.528] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+linux.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca", attempt 1
[17:47:56.528] SSH Resolver called for host: linux.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca
[17:47:56.529] Setting up SSH remote "linux.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca"
[17:47:56.554] Using commit id "d69a79b73808559a91206d73d7717ff5f798f23c" and quality "stable" for server
[17:47:56.556] Install and start server if needed
[17:47:56.559] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[17:47:56.621] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
[17:47:56.624] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 60292 linux.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca bash
[17:47:56.628] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[17:47:56.739] > 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[17:47:56.740] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[17:47:56.749] > 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
[17:48:00.242] > Password: 
[17:48:00.243] Showing password prompt
[17:48:03.389] Got password response
[17:48:03.390] "install" wrote data to terminal: "********"
[17:48:03.430] > 
> 
[17:48:05.752] > c08609cdaa4d: running
> 
[17:48:05.784] > Acquiring lock on /u2/spahooja/.vscode-server/bin/d69a79b73808559a91206d73d7717f
> f5f798f23c/vscode-remote-lock.spahooja.d69a79b73808559a91206d73d7717ff5f798f23c 
> 
[17:48:05.794] > flock: 99: Bad file descriptor     
> Installation already in progress...
> c08609cdaa4d##24##
> 
[17:48:05.794] Received install output: c08609cdaa4d##24##
[17:48:05.795] Server installation process already in progress - waiting and retrying
[17:48:06.095] "install" terminal command done
[17:48:06.095] Install terminal quit with output: 
[17:48:06.801] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 60292 linux.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca bash
[17:48:06.803] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[17:48:06.837] > 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[17:48:06.837] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[17:48:06.852] > 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
>     > 
> 
> 
[17:48:09.780] > Password: 
[17:48:09.781] Showing password prompt
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like vs code installation is stuck on your server (note: "Server installation process already in progress - waiting and retrying"). I was in the same situation where installation was stuck due to lack of space and fixed it by removing .vscode-server folder and re-initializing the server side state. I'm sure there is a better way to fix this, but if you're stuck, this is a quick way to fix this (though you'll have to setup your remote extensions again).

Answer (score 3):

do the following

1. close vscode
2. cd ~/.vscode-server/data/User
3. rm -rf workspaceStorage
4. start vscode again

Answer (score 1):

You basically have to delete the `.vscode-server` folder on your remote school computer using a normal ssh terminal and then reset the configuration on VS Code to access the file system on the remote computer again